# update field by 1

Tags: php, mysql

When wanting to update field completed_status by one when this form is submitted, it is staying at 0. The query $submission is the update for the users tables.
This is the code I have been using:

```
$user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
if (isset($_POST['doPersonal'])) {

    if (empty($err)) {

        $Sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Sex']);
        $Second_Nationality = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Second_Nationality']);
        $Birth_Place = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Birth_Place']);
        $Birth_Country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Birth_Country']);
        $children = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['children']);

        $the_query =   "INSERT INTO personal (user_id, Sex, Second_Nationality, 
Birth_Place, Birth_Country, children)
VALUES ('$user_id', '$Sex', '$Second_Nationality','$Birth_Place', '$Birth_Country',
'$children')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Sex=VALUES(Sex), Second_Nationality=VALUES(Second_Nationality),
Birth_Place=VALUES(Birth_Place) , children=VALUES(children)";



        // query is ok?
        if (mysql_query($the_query, $link) ){

            // redirect to user profile
            header('Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $user_id);

            $submission= "update users set completed_status=completed_status+1 where 
id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Uhm, how about actually executing the `$submission` query?

Comment: the main problem is 1) Redirecting before update query and 2) you have not executed the update query

Comment: @BPRAM Redirecting is not a problem. Code should stil run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above code we can see that you are `redirecting` the page before the `update query` so please modify it as,

```
if (mysql_query($the_query, $link) ){

           $submission= "update users set completed_status=completed_status+1 where 
id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";

           mysql_query($submission,$link);  // to execute the update query              

          // redirect to user profile
          header('Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $user_id);


}
```

Comment: In fact, code after `header` will still run. It just instructs PHP to send out a specific header, that is why you normally write `exit` after your redirects. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php).

Comment: Don't trust an unsanitised session, consider using prepared statements and escaping anything that could come from a browser.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't call the mysql_query:

```
$submission= "update users set completed_status=completed_status+1 where 
id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";
mysql_query($submission, $link);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to run the query.

```
    if (mysql_query($the_query, $link)){

        $submission= "update users set completed_status=completed_status+1 where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";
        mysql_query($submission, $link);

        // redirect to user profile
        header('Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $user_id);

    }
```

Please note that [the redirect does not affect anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2747803/468793) (even though others told you here). I just put it after the query because of a habit. Code after the redirect will still run, you just don't see the output in the browser. If you want to stop execution after the redirect, you can use `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your last `if` block:

```
if (mysql_query($the_query, $link)) {
  $query = 'update users set completed_status=completed_status+1 where id = ' . $_SESSION[user_id];
  mysql_query($query, $link);

  // redirect to user profile
  header('Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $user_id);
}
```

However, it's rather ambigous that you're using `$user_id` as well as `$_SESSION['user_id']`. Are these two different user_id's?