# PHP does the code break after a redirect?

Tags: php, function, redirect

I have a very basic question... In a php function I'm redirecting if a value returns FALSE otherwise continuing the code.

```
flibbertigibbet()
{
   $value = true_or_false();

   if ($value == FALSE)
   {
       //redirect to another controller method
   }

   //the rest of the code
}
```

What happens after the redirect? Does the code break or does a little execute if say.. the redirect takes longer to load?

Is it good practice to use `exit()` after redirects?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2747803/1017165) answer.

Comment: Most people use `foo` or `bar`, but `flibbertigibbet` is good, too.

Comment: @arxanas `foo` and `bar` are soo last season..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code will continue to execute - not just when the redirect takes longer, but each time nd through to the end.

Whether you use `exit()` depends on whether or not you *want* the rest of the code to be executed. You might set a `header()` and send a new address, but you can still execute things afterwards - like updating a database or some other bits.

I normally think it is best to do all your required updating and send the `header()` right at the end of a page - makes debugging much easier and more intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Just setting a redirect header does nothing on its own. ALWAYS `exit` or `die` after setting a Location header (unless you know exactly what you are doing)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by redirect. Yes, it will never run the rest of the code if it's something like:
`header("Location: http://newurl.com");`

Otherwise, unless there's a good reason for it not to come back (infinate loops, you're trying to `include` content which is taking too long and have not set a timeout, you use an `exit()`...), then the rest of the code will be run as soon as the if condition code has finished running.

Comment: Are you sure it will not run the rest of the code?  That [sounds wrong to me](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).  Verify the claim perhaps?

Comment: The code will still execute. You can test this really easily by sending two `header()` commands. The page will open to the second.