# delay when redirecting with php header("Refresh")

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why I have to call ‘exit’ after redirection through header(‘Location..’) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php)

In order to not be able to acces the mainpage.php without loggin in, I start the mainpage.php with following code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        header("Refresh: 0; url=hauptseite_slim.php");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

This does exactly what I want, **but**, the problem is, it is very ugly, because for a little moment, there mainpage shows up. How can I avoid this effect?

Comment: By not outputting the page. `exit(header(..));` is commonly advised. And a `Location:` might be the better alternative.

Comment: Just a Note...... This: if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) Should not be used to check if user is logged in. the Session could be easily highjacked. The user should be re-validated on each page load.

Comment: How do sites like ebay, facebook, and google keep a user logged in?

Comment: By regenerating session id on each page load, calling session values, database values, and browser cookie, running them through a validation Method/Function, and returning value.

Comment: `header("location:page.php"); exit;` - The exit stops any additional code from loading.

Answer (score 3):

why dont you use `header("location: hauptseite_slim.php");` ?

---

this is what i think the best practice :

```
header("location: hauptseite_slim.php");
exit;
```

Comment: Won't hinder the aforementioned page output. Also, answers ought to be more than a [one-liner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156941/one-liner-answers). If it ends in a question mark, it possibly isn't even.

Comment: it's because i usually use this code to throw to one page, havent used the technique you used above, and havent compared them yet. but yes I agree with other's comments, it should add exit after to make sure the code will be halted after. will edit my answer

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want the html after the if statement to be sent, just return.

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        header("Refresh: 0; url=hauptseite_slim.php");
        return;
    }
```