# not sending email in php with header from email id

Tags: php

I am using the following code along with HTML for header .

**$email="example@example.com"; in the  example and I want to implement variable in its place.
Code  as posted below but its not showing error nor sending email.**

I have tried the following links [PHP email form not sending information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389661/php-email-form-not-sending-information) , [PHP Sending Emails with File Attachments - Email Not Sending At All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004377/php-sending-emails-with-file-attachments-email-not-sending-at-all) .

I have tried

```
$headers .= "From: <".$email.">\n";
```

and

$headers .= $email;

This displays $email in the label **from header in email**.

But its working fine till this line:

```
$headers .= 'From: ' .$email. "\r\n";
```

This above line is not sending email if I remove this line it works but it does not add From email id to the header.

Please help me out it does not show any error and I have tried many variations to the above code but still stumped.

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['contact'];

$subject = "feedback";
$question = $_REQUEST['question'];


$body = "<html>
<head>

</html>";
$mime_boundary = "<<<--==+X[".md5(time())."]\r\n\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n" ."Content-Type:text/html;"."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:'.$email. "\r\n";


$to ='example@example.com';
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
echo "<script>alert(' message  sent.');</script>";

?>
```

Comment: Could you add the rest of your code, please?

Comment: added code please dont downvote this question.

Comment: So everything is working, aside from the part where you add the 'From' line to the headers? If that line is there, it won't send the email; but if you comment it out, it will? In which case - what are you adding as an email? And what do you mean by it's not sending the email - are there errors in the SMTP log? Or does everything look like it's working, but the email never arrives?

Comment: Yes everything looks like its working but email is not arriving and if I remove **$headers .= 'From:'.$email. "\r\n";** it arrives but without from email in the header label the rest works perfect.I dont know why this is not working tried many variations.Please upvote the question It would help me a great deal.

Comment: What do your SMTP error logs say? What is the actual value of `$email` when the form is sent? In the past I've had issues with mail being discarded when the From address was an invalid email address, so might that be causing the issue? Can you try replacing `$email` with your own email address?

Comment: how to get SMTP error log ?  $email ="example@example.com" .I will also try with valid email also.

Comment: I tried valid id and its still not working

Comment: In your question, you have the line formatted as "From: $email" - in the code you've posted, there's no space between the colon and the email address. That might be an issue.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that the `Content-type:text\html;` needs a trailing semi-colon. Basically - can you split the `$headers` into three sections, and try commenting out each part to see if it's a problem with one of the other lines?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28830/discussion-between-james-patrick-and-andrewsi)

Comment: I have posted few queries on chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use standard [mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) function, then try this(do not add "From" header to $headers):

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f ".$email);
```

Comment: Tried your solution still not working.I have added the code above.Please dont downvote my question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with one of the servers I were dealing with. Apparently in my server, not specifying "From" header sends email from the default mail address of your account (in case of a shared hosting). I chose this solution as an ad-hoc fix and specified my actual from address in "Reply-To" header. This way, I can still receive the replies sent to those email threads.

This method seems feasible for just functional email addresses (eg., support@example.com)only. If you are using this approach for a user's email address (eg., john@example.com), chances are that the recipient might think of your email as a spam.