# PHP variable over POST with a formular

Tags: php, html

I want to send a variable via POST. The variable should not be in the URL like in this formular:

```html
    <form action="index.php?content=contact" method="POST">
        <a class="article-input-a">Name:</a><br><input name="name" type="text"  maxlength="30"><br>
        <a class="article-input-a">E-Mail Adresse:</a><br><input name="email" type="text"  maxlength="30" placeholder="beispiel@email.de"><br>
        <a class="article-input-a">Website:</a><br><input name="website" type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="www.beispiel-website.de"><br>        
        <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">Beitrag erstellen</button> 
</form>
```

In this formular i can send the variables, but i dont see them in the URL.
And i can get the variables over `$_POST['name']`. Now i want to send the variable **$random** with the formular submite button.

I hope you can undestand me.

Comment: Are you *wanting* to see the variable in the URL? If so, use GET. If not, use a `<input type="hidden">` input.

Comment: Have you looked here?:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820013/html-form-php-post-to-self-to-validate-or-submit-to-new-page

Comment: you're using POST. the form fields will never show up in the url, because they'll be in the message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correcty you want hidden inputs

```
<form action="index.php?content=contact" method="POST">
    <a class="article-input-a">Name:</a><br><input name="name" type="text"  maxlength="30"><br>
    <a class="article-input-a">E-Mail Adresse:</a><br><input name="email" type="text"  maxlength="30" placeholder="beispiel@email.de"><br>
    <a class="article-input-a">Website:</a><br><input name="website" type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="www.beispiel-website.de"><br>        
    <input type="hidden" name="content" value="contact" />
    <input type="hidden" name="verName" value="varValue" />
    <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">Beitrag erstellen</button>   
</form>
```

sending variables as part of the url is a GET request, not a POST request

then you access like

```
$_POST['varName']
```

Answer (score 2):

To see them in your URL you need to use `GET` not `POST`.

```
   <form action="index.php?content=contact" method="GET">
    <a class="article-input-a">Name:</a><br><input name="name" type="text"  maxlength="30"><br>
    <a class="article-input-a">E-Mail Adresse:</a><br><input name="email" type="text"  maxlength="30" placeholder="beispiel@email.de"><br>
    <a class="article-input-a">Website:</a><br><input name="website" type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="www.beispiel-website.de"><br>        
    <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">Beitrag erstellen</button>
```

To send the variable, add

```
<input type=hidden name='random' value="<?php echo $random; ?>">
```

This will make a hidden variable that will be submitted.

Then access using `$_GET['random']`. But it will be in your URL as `?Name=&E-Mail=&Website=`

Answer (score 0):

to send that variable, you need to create a hidden field, that hold the value of that random number
`<input type=hidden value="<?php echo $random; ?>">`