# The validation not working after there is redirection in the form

Tags: php, validation

i'm trying to validate and redirect to another page with two variables(dates). The validation going well if i don't redirect the page.
If i use

```
action = "pagingstatic.php"
```

The validation not working.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Въвеждане на дата</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
     <?php
     // define variables and set to empty values
        function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
        }

     $from_dateErr = $to_dateErr =  '';
     $from_date = $to_date = '';

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
        {
            $valid = true;
            if (empty($_GET["from_date"]) or empty($_GET["to_date"])) {
            $from_dateErr = "Задължително поле";
            $to_dateErr = "Задължително поле";

            } else {
                $from_date = test_input($_GET["from_date"]);
                $to_date = test_input($_GET["to_date"]);
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/[0-9\\-]/",$from_date)or !preg_match("/[0-9\\-]/",$to_date)) {
                $from_dateErr = "формат: 0-9 и разделящи символи - и /";
                $to_dateErr = "формат: 0-9 и разделящи символи - и /";

                }    
            }

        }
     ?>
    <div class = "login-box">
        <p class="headp">Язовир Искър</p>
        <div class = "login">
            <!--
            action = "pagingstatic.php"
            LOGO NEK <div class="image"></div> -->
            <p>Зареждане на таблица от PostgreSQL по зададена дата.</p>
            <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
            <form  action = "pagingstatic.php" method = "GET">
                <label for="odata">От дата</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "from_date">
                  <span class="error">* <?php echo $from_dateErr;?></span>
                <br />
                <label for="odata">До дата</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "to_date">
                  <span class="error">* <?php echo $from_dateErr;?></span>                
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Покажи таблица">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
      <?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $from_date;
echo "<br>";
echo $to_date;
echo "<br>";
echo $act;
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you give me any suggestions?

Thanks for the help! Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Въвеждане на дата</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
     <?php
     // define variables and set to empty values
        function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
        }

     $from_dateErr = $to_dateErr =  '';
     $from_date = $to_date = $act = '';

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
        {
            $valid = true;
            if (empty($_GET["from_date"]) or empty($_GET["to_date"])) {
            $from_dateErr = "Задължително поле";
            $to_dateErr = "Задължително поле";
            $valid = false;
            } else {
                $from_date = test_input($_GET["from_date"]);
                $to_date = test_input($_GET["to_date"]);
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/[0-9\\-]/",$from_date)or !preg_match("/[0-9\\-]/",$to_date)) {
                $from_dateErr = "формат: 0-9 и разделящи символи - и /";
                $to_dateErr = "формат: 0-9 и разделящи символи - и /";
                $valid = false;
                }    
            }

  //if valid then action redirect
  if($valid){
    header("location:pagingstatic.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
   exit();
  }
        }
     ?>
    <div class = "login-box">
        <p class="headp">Test</p>
        <div class = "login">
            <!--
            action = "pagingstatic.php"
            LOGO NEK <div class="image"></div> -->
            <p>Зареждане на таблица от PostgreSQL по зададена дата.</p>
            <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
            <form  method = "GET">
                <label for="odata">От дата</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "from_date">
                  <span class="error">* <?php echo $from_dateErr;?></span>
                <br />
                <label for="odata">До дата</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "to_date">
                  <span class="error">* <?php echo $from_dateErr;?></span>                
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Покажи таблица">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
      <?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $from_date;
echo "<br>";
echo $to_date;
echo "<br>";
echo $act;
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the name of your page which code you posted here? and why are you using `header()` when you pass `action=pagenamehere` in your form?

Comment: you can use `session_start()` to keep the variables for the user

Comment: Its test_table.php

Comment: Why so negative votes for this question?

Comment: Your question is not clear. That's may be A reason to downvote.

Comment: did you get an **header already sent** error, when you trying to redirect using `header()`?

Comment: i used this topic for the header https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820013/html-form-php-post-to-self-to-validate-or-submit-to-new-page

Comment: Use session as to pass the data to any page after redirection. Hope this will help to you. [PHP Session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: @Ankit Singh no

Comment: So what all you want to do is pull your data to another page. Right?

Comment: Yes, but after the validation

Comment: I will edit my question then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use session to hold your value.But for now you can try this:

```
if($valid){
    header("location:somepage.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solving my issue :)