# Redirect page using php

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, hyperlink, href

I try this to redirect page using PHP:

`if($var="error")
 echo '<script>location.href="404.php"</script>';`

Works, but, is possible redirect the page directly from PHP?

Comment: should have been a very simple web search `php redirect`. WOuld have found it faster than it took to sign up on this site

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please always search before asking. A search for `redirect using php` would have given you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

```
header('Location: http://google.com');
exit();
```

Comment: +1 for [exit after header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

PHP redirects are done with `header()`

```
header('Location : '404.php');
```

[DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this does not compile. You have one extra `'` in the string.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible if you do it before any content:

```
<?php header("Location: 404.php"); ?>
```

If you have sent any content to the client, however, it will not work. This means even a doctype or whitespaces before the first PHP block.

Also, if you want to stop processing that page there just add `exit;` or `exit();` there.

Answer (score -1):

Yes... you can use the location headers. 
Example:

```
<?php header('Location: 404.php'); ?>
```

However you can not use this if there is any kind of output before this statement.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function

```
header("Location: 404.php");
exit();
```