# Passing GET variables using header in PHP

Tags: php, forms, session, get

I'm coding a "users-only" access for a site, and when the user is not logged in the dashboard is redirecting to the login page.

```
<?php
session_start();
$logged= $_SESSION['logged'];

if(!$logged){
    header("Location:http://www.someweb.com/system/login.php?logged_off=1");
}

?>
```

but the login page is not receiving the GET variable, can you please tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Other than the missing space after `Location:`, nothing really wrong with this code. You'll have to debug it yourself. e.g. do `var_dump($_GET)` in your login script. use a browser debugger to see if there's any redirects going on which could be stripping the parameters, etc...

Comment: Do you see this argument in the redirected address bar of the browser?

Comment: Are you sure that what's happening is this? What if instead you actually get a 404 which in returns redirects you to the hp?

Comment: should always call `exit();` after header

Comment: @Dagon Nope! Because with `exit()` you'll exit the WHOLE script...

Comment: @pc-shooter, that is what `exit` does and it should be used with `header/redirect`.

Comment: @pc-shooter What websites do you maintain? I'd like to check them out... and turn on "ignore redirects" on my browser :)

Comment: mmm just added exit(); and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @sjagr I personally try to work without `header` .....

Comment: You have your `logged`already in the Session. So why not just calling the Session entry on the login page??

Comment: @pc-shooter sorry(not really) your simply wrong on that one

Comment: please feel free to post your answers and I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Dagon Go for it bro. The OP's asking ^^^ - So, butter too, yummo. Bonus - Gonna get +1 plus added salt.

Comment: @Dagon agreeing for that example, but.... are you putting an exit every time you use header?

Comment: @pc-shooter Any dev on my team that wouldn't put an `exit` after every `header` redirect would get a serious talking to. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2747803/1188035) among it being a well-known fact

Comment: @Dagon I've just read the link of Fred-ii (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2747803/)..... Oh man, you were so right! This is what i like here, always learning.

Comment: @pc-shooter its o,k I'm sure your better at yodelling and cheeses than i am :-)

Comment: @pc-shooter The beauty of Google is not just the pretty pictures and the God awful news they show us in this world. There is always better light at the end of the tunnel. In this case, it was Wile E.'s painted version that got us all slamming into the Road Runner's wall. ;) *Meep Meep!*

Comment: @pc-shooter +1 for graciously accepting critique and admitting error :)

Comment: @Dagon Stereotype! I don't have a cow at home, If you know what I mean && Fred -ii- lol

Comment: I'll put away the salt shaker now. Unless @Dagon wants more.

Comment: @sjagr Otherwise we wouldn' learn anything would we

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [**header location**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), you should call [`exit();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

***Why?*** Because the script's execution will not be terminated.

Parentheses `()` are optional, `exit` is a language construct not a function, and they actually are a bad idea (PHP has more work to do if they exist), just a terrible habit I have.

Comment: theres no new questions on S.O just new ways to ask(and answer)

Comment: Exactly. There's more than one way to ask a hunter/trapper on how to skin a waskiwee wabbit.

Comment: With you up until "or any header" - setting a header along with content is perfectly normal. e.g. `header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($something);`

Comment: fell free to edit answer to make it better - no really please do

Comment: @Dagon +1 Maybe you should give me some lessons in PHP ;-)

Comment: the first lesson of PHP is never talk about PHP - well that makes my teaching life easier ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that added edit of yours is much better. I just polished it up a bit ;)

Comment: you just want your name to show up you glory hog :)\

Comment: ☮ Look at me shine! I'm a ★ STAR ★