# PHPExcel Force Download Issue

Tags: php, apache, phpexcel, xlsx, force-download

I know this might have been asked in several pieces, but I could not find an exact answer to the issue. I am using PHPExcel to generate an Excel file (obviously), and the code works to generate the file, but not when I include the code for Force Download, it corrupts the file. My latest version of the script looks like this:

```
function make_xls_spreadsheet(){

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Set the save path */
define('XLSX_SAVE_PATH', 'tmp/');

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');

/** PHPExcel */
include 'PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';


/* Create a new PHPExcel Object */
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();


/* Add some metadata to the file */
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.");

/* Set active worksheet to first */
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Segments');

/* Add some data to the worksheet */
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');


/* Write to server */
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

$filename = "tony1.xlsx";

// Works fine up to here

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
//$objWriter->save('php://output');
$objWriter->save(XLSX_SAVE_PATH . $filename);
readfile(XLSX_SAVE_PATH . $filename);


echo "DONE!";

$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($objPHPExcel);



}
```

Remember, when I remove the force code section, the file generates and I can FTP it down fine. However, doing both generating and forcing the file gives me a corrupt file. Normally I can click "Open & Repair" (Office2011 MacOSX) but obviously this is not desirable.

Could someone please help me understand:

1. Why it is being generated as corrupt? And why it works fine when I don't force download.
2. What the proper order for saving/forcing is (using PHP's header() function)
3. If there is a better way of doing this.

Much appreciated!!

**** Update **** Here is the code when I click "Fix & Repair":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>Repair Result to tony1 03178.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Errors were detected in file 'Macintosh HD:Users:tony.diloreto:Downloads:tony1.xlsx'</summary>
    <additionalInfo><info>Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.</info></additionalInfo>
</recoveryLog>
```

Comment: instead of saving it to a file, save it to `php://output`, unless you need a local copy then `$objWriter->save('php://output');`

Comment: Thanks - do I need the readfile() line then? What would go in it if I do?

Comment: replace everything after the line `$objWriter =` .. with `$objWriter->save('php://output');`

Comment: No dice - new bottom of script is:


    `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    return;`

Comment: fyi "no dice" and "Close but no cigar." is a tad condescending to the *free* help

Comment: what exactly happens now? and whats `return;` ?

Comment: apologies - obv peace & love for all the free help. =D

I removed the `return;` (added just to ensure the function ended) but still did not work. :-(

Comment: all good, but `does not work` can mean many things ;)

Comment: Sorry - file is still generated, but when I save & open, I still get an error opening the file. The error is: "excel could not open because some content is unreadable". OSX - Excel2011

Comment: save the file, open with text editor, check for php errors in the top

Comment: I'm still not having any luck - here is the file http://tonydiloreto.com/files/tony1.xlsx
Would you mind trying to open if you have a non-mac?

Comment: open that file in text editior - scroll down - see something funny?

Comment: When I open in Sublime, all I see are quartets of numbers all the way down. When I try in TextWrangler, it shows me folders of .XML files, but they look fine to me. Which Mac text-editor would you recommend?

Comment: never used a mac. it's full of html after the excel, add `exit();` to end of function

Comment: You are a genius among men! If you ever come to NYC let me know and I'll buy you a beer! Thank you so much Dagon!

Answer (score 2):

// answer actually belongs to @Dagon

The answer is actually straightforward, only needing a simple `exit();` call.

Final code block:

```
function make_xls_spreadsheet(){

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');

/** PHPExcel */
include 'PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';


/* Create a new PHPExcel Object */
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

/** Determine filename **/
$filename = "tony1.xlsx";

/** Set header information **/
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


/* Add some metadata to the file */
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.");

/* Set active worksheet to first */
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Segments');

/* Add some data to the worksheet */
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

exit();

}
```

Comment: actully the 2nd question i answered today with the answer of `exit();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264997/passing-get-variables-using-header-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This spits out the excel file to the browser:

```
readfile(XLSX_SAVE_PATH . $filename);
```

and then you spit this out, which becomes PART of the excel file as downloaded by the browser

```
echo "DONE!";
```

essentially you're sending

```
[excel data]DONE!
```

when Excel is expecting only

```
[excel data]
```

Comment: Close but no cigar. It still says some content is "unreadable" and it must fix & repair. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify File.php like this :

protected static $_useUploadTempDirectory   = TRUE;

in folder phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared (it's not the best way but it worked for me).