# PHP redirect Loop error issue

Tags: php, redirect, infinite-loop

I have searched the forum but couldnt understand the PHP redirect page loop issue.

I have a simple PHP page:

```
 <?php include('core/init.core.php');


$page_request="graph";

if (isset($_SESSION['account']['user_role']) && 
    $_SESSION['account']['user_role'] =='coaching_manager' ||
    $_SESSION['account']['user_role'] =='OEM'||
    $_SESSION['account']['user_role'] =='GM'||
    $_SESSION['account']['user_role'] =='director'||
    $_SESSION['account']['user_role'] =='proactive_coaching_manager') {
    $page_request="graph";
}
else
    $page_request='request_form';

if (isset($_GET['page_request'])) {
    $page_request=$_GET['page_request'];
}

$user = get_user_on_uin(strval($_SESSION['account']['ein']));

//var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($user));
//die();

if(mysqli_num_rows($user)>0){ //if user exists in the user table in sql


    //get user data from user table in sql
    $user=$user->fetch_assoc();

        //update user details in db
    update_user_on_uin($_SESSION['account']['firstname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['lastname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['email'],
        $_SESSION['account']['phone'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['managerein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ouc'],
        $_SESSION['account']['user_role'],
        $_SESSION['account']['som'],
        $_SESSION['account']['gm']);

    switch ($user['user_role']){

        case 'engineer':
            //check if user have changed their role/ouc if yes then resetup the user
        if ($_SESSION['account']['ouc']==$user['ouc']) {

           if ($page_request=='request_form') {
            header('Location: request-form-engineer.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_requests') {
            header('Location: view-requests-engineer.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_accepted_requests') {
            header('Location: view-accepted-requests.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_rejected_requests') {
            header('Location: view-rejected-requests.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_coach_assigned_requests') {
            header('Location: view-coachassigned-requests.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_completed_requests') {
            header('Location: view-completed-requests.php');
            die();
        } 
    } 

    else{
        update_user_on_uin($_SESSION['account']['firstname'],
            $_SESSION['account']['lastname'],
            $_SESSION['account']['email'],
            $_SESSION['account']['phone'],
            $_SESSION['account']['ein'],
            $_SESSION['account']['managerein'],
            $_SESSION['account']['ouc'],
            $_SESSION['account']['user_role'],
            $_SESSION['account']['som'],
            $_SESSION['account']['gm']);
            //header('Location: setup-account.php?message=update');
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
        die();
    }


    case 'manager':

    if ($_SESSION['account']['ouc']==$user['ouc']) {

        if ($page_request=='request_form') {
            header('Location: request-form-om.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_requests') {
            header('Location: view-requests-om.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_accepted_requests') {
            header('Location: view-accepted-requests.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_rejected_requests') {
            header('Location: view-rejected-requests.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_coach_assigned_requests') {
            header('Location: view-coachassigned-requests.php');
            die();
        }
        elseif ($page_request=='view_completed_requests') {
            header('Location: view-completed-requests.php');
            die();
        }            
    } 

    else{
     update_user_on_uin($_SESSION['account']['firstname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['lastname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['email'],
        $_SESSION['account']['phone'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['managerein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ouc'],
        $_SESSION['account']['user_role'],
        $_SESSION['account']['som'],
        $_SESSION['account']['gm']);
            //header('Location: setup-account.php?message=update');
     header('Location: dashboard.php');
               // header('Location: setup-account.php?message=update');
     die();
 }



 case 'coaching_manager':

 if ($_SESSION['account']['ouc']==$user['ouc']) {

    if ($page_request=='request_form') {
        header('Location: request-form-coaching-manager.php');
        die();
    }
    elseif ($page_request=='view_requests') {
        header('Location: view-requests-coaching-manager.php');
        die();
    }
    elseif ($page_request=='view_accepted_requests') {
        header('Location: view-accepted-requests.php');
        die();
    }
    elseif ($page_request=='view_rejected_requests') {
        header('Location: view-rejected-requests.php');
        die();
    }
    elseif ($page_request=='view_coach_assigned_requests') {
        header('Location: view-coachassigned-requests.php');
        die();
    }
    elseif ($page_request=='view_completed_requests') {
        header('Location: view-completed-requests.php');
        die();
    }
    elseif ($page_request=='graph') {
        header('Location: graph.php');
        die();
    }    

}

else{
    update_user_on_uin($_SESSION['account']['firstname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['lastname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['email'],
        $_SESSION['account']['phone'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['managerein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ouc'],
        $_SESSION['account']['user_role'],
        $_SESSION['account']['som'],
        $_SESSION['account']['gm']);
            //header('Location: setup-account.php?message=update');
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
        //header('Location: setup-account.php?message=update');
    die();
}


case 'coach':

if ($_SESSION['account']['ouc']==$user['ouc']) {

   if ($page_request=='request_form') {
    header('Location: request-form-coach.php');
    die();
}
elseif ($page_request=='view_requests') {
    header('Location: view-requests-coach.php');
    die();
}
elseif ($page_request=='view_accepted_requests') {
    header('Location: view-accepted-requests.php');
    die();
}
elseif ($page_request=='view_rejected_requests') {
    header('Location: view-rejected-requests.php');
    die();
}
elseif ($page_request=='view_coach_assigned_requests') {
    header('Location: view-coachassigned-requests.php');
    die();
}
elseif ($page_request=='view_completed_requests') {
    header('Location: view-completed-requests.php');
    die();
} 

}

else{
    update_user_on_uin($_SESSION['account']['firstname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['lastname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['email'],
        $_SESSION['account']['phone'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['managerein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ouc'],
        $_SESSION['account']['user_role'],
        $_SESSION['account']['som'],
        $_SESSION['account']['gm']);
            //header('Location: setup-account.php?message=update');
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
                //header('Location: setup-account.php?message=update');
    die();
}


default:
break;


    }//end of switch

}   //end of if block

else{
    //header('Location: setup-account.php?message=new_user');
    //var_dump("expression");
   // die();
    if( insert_user($_SESSION['account']['firstname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['lastname'],
        $_SESSION['account']['email'],
        $_SESSION['account']['phone'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['managerein'],
        $_SESSION['account']['ouc'],
        $_SESSION['account']['user_role'],
        $_SESSION['account']['som'],
        $_SESSION['account']['gm']) )
    {


        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        die();

    }
    else
    {
        var_dump('Sorry we do not recognise you. bye!');
        die();
    }
           // header("Location: dashboard.php");
           // die(); */

}


    //if no, redirect to role selection page
?>
```

This page name is `dashboard.php`
`init.core.php` page starts the session.

The task is simple. If user found then update user details with `$_Session` details. If not then add a new user and redirect to this page to display relevant info. I can see it executes the else part i.e. inserts user but It inserts alot of records in the database before eventually giving up stating `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Whats the name of the file this code lives in?

Comment: Please use `exit;` unless you explicitly want to **abort** the script with a `die()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly The manual explicitly states: `die — Equivalent to exit`. They both abort the script. And when doing a header redirect, it is actually suggested to abort.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) Please count the usage of `die()` and the usage of `exit;`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn See  Hayley Watson's opinion on `die()` at [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)

Comment: This `$user=$user->fetch_assoc();` is at best going to cause a memory leak

Comment: Your `switch()` statement is badly coded [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) A case does not require a `{}` wrap. Also there is not much point in coding a switch if you have only one case.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have alot of other cases...I presented one case to save space

Comment: @Rob The URL name is dashboard.php

Comment: Looks like you keep hitting the header("Location:dashboard.php) for whatever reason.

Comment: @Rob just added the code as it is. Please check now and suggest?

Comment: @RiggsFolly My point is that `die` is the same thing as `exit` and even the manual states they are equivalent. `exit;` will do the exact same thing as `die;`. They both are language constructs and take in an optional status code or message that will be output to the user. `die` is just a alias of `exit`. Hayley Watson's comment doesn't change the fact that they are exactly the same. With redirects it is suggested to use them to prevent the rest of the page from running, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php

Comment: What is `get_user_on_uin()` actually returning?  Is it a mysqli result set?  For whatever reason, mysqli_num_rows($user) appears to always return either 0 or false.

Comment: `function get_user_on_uin($uin){
  $connection = get_db();
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE uin='.$uin;
  return $connection->query($query);
 }`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn With respect that link is not to a manual. die signifies a error termination and exit a clean termination.

Comment: @RiggsFolly in any case...it didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are setting the value for `$_SESSION['account']['id']`.  Without that being set, it is going to always go to the primary else and insert a new user.

That being said, are you calling `session_start()` at the beginning of the script?  If not, then the values will not be maintained between script calls.

Comment: Don't worry about the `$_SESSION['account']['id']` I am setting it up correctly (double checked) just didn't show here

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` at the beginning of the script as well?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Yes I am... I going to try to add the whole page as it