# Check redirect source

Tags: php

I have a form to edit an entry, after the user presses the submit button it executes the `includes/edit.php?id=XXX` script and then redirects using the `header('Location: ../index.php');` to the index page where all the entries are being displayed.

On the index page, I want to create a condition:

if the index page is accessed via a redirect from the `edit.php?id=XXX` page, then show a success message to notify the user that the edit was succesfull.

How should this condition look like?

```
<?php
require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/config.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){ //if login in session is not set
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com/app/login.php");
}
$query = ("SELECT * FROM archive ORDER by id DESC");
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

/*if (condition){
   //show success message
}*/
?>
```

Comment: Important: add an `exit()` or `die()` after your `header(...)` otherwise the redirect will give problems.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, while I didn't encountered any problems with the redirect yet, I added the `exit()` after the `header('Location: ....')`.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` isn't reliable and you need to read on http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ about it. I'd use `strpos()` or `stripos()` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at this var :

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

As it will return the page from where you come before this one:

So you could just do :

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ==  "edit.php?id=XXX"){
 // your code here
}
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` isn't reliable and you need to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ about it.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply try this :

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']))
{
       // your success message
}
```

Comment: While I find your answer very useful (might even apply it in my case), I wanted to know about the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`, I had to accept another answer but I upvoted yours since it's an awesome solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- I would suggest to redirect immediately and not execute more code after the location header is set:

  ```
  if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){ //if login in session is not set
      header("Location: http://www.domain.com/app/login.php");
      exit();
  }
  ```

  - If $_SESSION['login'] is **not set**: redirect and exit.
  - You might consider the rest of the code as one big "else" (= if $_SESSION['login'] **is set**).
  - To answer the question from comments: without the exit, the code below will be executed .. and doing that query is not really necessary. Thats why its better to end the program flow by adding an `exit`. Referencing: [Why I have to call 'exit' after redirection through header('Location..') in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php)
- And for the condition you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` or `$_GET['id']` to check the page you are coming from. Just compare the strings or parts of them.

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I want to ask you something, without using the exit(); line, after the condition above returns true doesn't it go and execute the code inside proceeding with the redirect, ignoring the code below the if's end bracket anyway?

Comment: I've added the answer to your question above.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a $_SESSION variable with messages you can then display all messages and clear the list afterwards.

Adding a message:

```
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['messages']) ) {
    # initialize messages
    $_SESSION['messages'] = [];
}

# Add a new message:
$_SESSION['messages'][] = 'Something was a success!';
```

Reading messages:

```
# If there are messages not displayed
if ( isset($_SESSION['messages']) && is_array($_SESSION['messages']) ) {
    foreach ( $_SESSION['messages'] as $message ) {
        echo $message . '<br>';
    }

    # Clear messages
    unset( $_SESSION['messages'] );
}
```

The suggested 'HTTP_REFERER' can be manipulated and browsers are not required to send it.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution that I used.