# Password System Not Doing Anything

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The code below is a login system. The username is Administrator and the Password is Password (You can change it later on) what it does now is after the form is sent it just displays the login page. I cant find anything wrong with it. Please help. The error_log file shows nothing. It might be the password not hashing correctly. As I set the password using

```
echo password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

and just inserting the result.

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
require 'settings.php';


if(count($_POST)>0) {


$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='" . $username . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(is_array($row)) {
$hash = $row['password'];
$passwordcheck = password_verify($password, $hash);
} 
if($hash == $passwordcheck){
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION["user_name"] = $row['username'];
} else {
$message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
mysqli_query("DELETE * FROM LoginAttempts WHERE IP='".$ip."'"); 
header("Location:dashboard.php");
}
}
?>
<div class="panel-body">
                    <form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="user_name" type="username" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                    if($locked == 'yes'){
                    echo "Sorry you are locked out of the system. Please try again in";
                    echo $timeleft;
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Edit: Now I get these errors: 
[15-Nov-2015 07:00:58 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'laughin1'@'176.31.10.37' (using password: NO) in /home/laughin1/public_html/admin/index.php on line 9
[15-Nov-2015 07:00:58 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/laughin1/public_html/admin/index.php on line 10
[15-Nov-2015 07:00:58 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/laughin1/public_html/admin/index.php on line 11
[15-Nov-2015 07:00:58 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/laughin1/public_html/admin/index.php on line 12
[15-Nov-2015 07:00:58 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/laughin1/public_html/admin/index.php on line 14
[15-Nov-2015 07:00:58 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/laughin1/public_html/admin/index.php on line 15

BUT if I change the MySQLi To MySQL everything is fine.

Comment: try `var_dump` your `$row`, what does it show? Also, after the line of `header`, it is better to add `exit()`

Comment: Yes. It is defiantly something wrong with the hashing because if I dehash the passwords it works.

Comment: you use `password_verify` to verify the password, you dont hash the login password again because it will generate a whole new password, thats why it doesn't match

Comment: @andrew thanks. However how do I check the password using the hash if that is stored in the password I previously hashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user register, you will use `password_hash` to hash their password and store in the database, and when a user try to login, you use `password_verify` to verify their password

Procedure:

```
register->password_hash()->save_in_db()
login->fetch_hash_column_from_their_username->password_verify()
if verified->set_session->redirect, else stay_in_the_same_page
```

Add some validation to your form, so that user cannot hit your database constantly which create high payload and prevent (slightly) some protection to your site

Also, after this line

```
header("Location:dashboard.php");
```

Add

```
exit();
```

For more info about why, click here [Why I have to call 'exit' after redirection through header('Location..') in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php?lq=1)

Update:

`password_verify` accept two argument, `( string $password , string $hash )`, you will put login password as the first argument, and put the hash stored from your database into the second argument. It will `return true` if match else `return false`

Comment: Does that mean I have to write two queries. 1. Getting the hash using the only user (this would be row['password'];) then verify using the now gathered hash and then check the now verified password with the one in the database? @Andrew

Comment: Theres only one query, fetch the hash from the form's username, so sth like `SELECT hash FROM user_table WHERE username = x`, and then you can verify the password using the `password_verify`

Comment: I saw one mistake..should be `if ($passwordcheck === true)`

Comment: why 3 === ? Also thanks for your help this has been really needed.

Comment: @user3579312 `==` compare exclude type, and `===` compare with type ...you can also write as `if ($passwordcheck)`, From doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I would be delighted to upvote. The solution works and I will also add parts to the password changing section. Cheers!

Comment: now it shows heaps of errors. I have listed them in the OP could you assist.

Comment: @user3579312 it would be better to open as another question as this looks like its about connection problem...did you alter your connection ? I use `PDO` so it may differ from my experience

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the password_verify comment by Andrew

> $encryptPassword = password_hash($users-signup-password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

The value in $encryptedPassord is stored in DB (typically), ie: on successful user signup.

On Login fetch the user's hash, typical select would be on email assuming
that's the unique identifier for users

> $hash = findUserByEmail($email); // dummy function, you implement this
>
> $isAuth = password_verify($users-login-password, $hash);

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

TIP: if the $isAuth is true then you should store a new hash of the password in the db, better to have dynamic hashes for each password.

Comment: There is only one user. This is for a administration panel.

Comment: exit prevents the remainder of the page to execute... the header just redirects.