# header is not working when called within a function

Tags: php, function

I have created a php file named `public.php` and have added few functions to it to reduce code redundancy. One of the functions is as follows.

```
/**
 * Checks if there is a valid session and navigates to the login page if false.
 * @return boolean true if session valid.
 */
function checkSession_auto() {
    if (checkSession()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //echo 'pass'; exit;
        header("location: accounts/login.php");
    }
}
```

I have verified that the `checkSession()` returns `false`, using an `echo` statement. Here's the problem.

> **The page does not navigates to `login.php`. Why?**

Thanks in advise!

Comment: You generally need to `exit` after you send a location header.

Comment: @Alex It usually doesn't needs the `exit` statement. Why in a function?

Comment: `header()` doesn't exit by itself, so when the function returns to the caller, it will just keep executing more code, and continue to render whatever page was originally called.

Comment: @alex Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem solved by adding `exit` statement after `header($string)`,
>   read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482105/headerstring-is-not-working-when-called-within-a-function#comment74020247_43482105).

It seems that the [exiting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) is mandatory after sending a location header unless you do not have any code (PHP or HTML) under header.

The `header` is only a line of data asking the browser to redirect. The rest of the page will still be served by PHP and can be looked at by the client by simply preventing the `header` command from executing.

Resources;

- [php - Should I call exit() after calling Location: header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3553698/2408342)
- [Why I have to call 'exit' after redirection through header('Location..') in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2747791/2408342)