# header location with id in php

Tags: php, header

Is it possible to put a row ID in `header()`? I tried to put `header()` inside an `if` statement but I always got a message of:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Here's my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_con,$query);
$target="Admin/upload/otherPic/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
if ($result){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
        echo "<script>
            alert('Record updated successfully!');
            </script>";
        header("Location: admin-viewacc.php?id='$result['id'];'");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db_con);
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: what is `$query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `fetch` the recordset ( presuming it is a `select` query ) and there is no need for additional single quotes around the ID in the header string.

This is liable to errors - if you output any html, whitespace etc before calling certain PHP functions you will trigger an error. To that end, do not add the javascript code - instead display a message on the next page.

```
if( $result ){

    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target ) ){

        $result = mysqli_query( $db_con, $query );
        while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() )$id=$rs->id;


        $target = 'Admin/upload/otherPic/' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name'] );


        echo "
            <script>
                alert('Record updated successfully!');
            </script>";

        header( "Location: admin-viewacc.php?id={$id}" );

    } else{
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error( $db_con );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
header("Location: admin-viewacc.php?id=" . $result['id']);
```

---

And it is good practise to use `exit` statement after `header($string)`, because it can get a little messy sometimes.

```
header("Location: admin-viewacc.php?id=" . $result['id']);
exit;
```

Read this - [header is not working when called within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43482105/2408342)