# Function still executes from link without active session

Tags: php, session, get

I got some code that executes with value's inside a `$_GET` and some code that checks for an active session. Yet, when I go to the link directly without active session it still executes the function and after that returns to the login page.

My code:

My loginheader:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['Username'])|| $_SESSION["Actief"] == 0|| 
    $_SESSION["Actief"] == 2) {
    return header("Location: main_login.php");
    exit();
}
```

My webpage (only the needed code):

```
require "../loginheader.php";
require "../AdminOnlyHeader.php";
// --some code with sql instructions--
$result = ExecuteQuery($sql);`
```

`AdminOnlyHeader` is just to check for admin status. This too seems to be bypassed by just entering a link.

So if you still don't understand what I mean, here's a short summary of what I do:

1. I make one of those links that contain the get data needed to execute it;
2. I log out and get returned to the login page;
3. I enter the the link I made before;
4. After some loading I am still on the login page but when I look at my database I see that the record has been updated and thus the function (`ExecuteQuery`) was executed.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `return` from

```
return header("Location: main_login.php");
```

We need two references to understand this:

- [**Return**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) part:

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file.

- **[Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php)** part:

> If you redirect but you don't `die()` / `exit()` the code is always executed and displayed.

---

Basically, since you returned, it won't reach the `exit()` part, meaning that it will return the execution to the main script - the one with the function that shouldn't be executed in this circumstance.

Comment: Works more or less, it does not execute the funtion (yeay) but it returns an 404 not found instead of the login page.

Comment: Do you have a `main_login.php` file? Is the url correct in the browser? @MiguelDP . Was it working before?

Comment: Ah I found what was causing it. I was inside another directory. I'll place an update if your methot worked once I figure out how to go back without changing that loginheader file.

Comment: Yup everything works now. I did remove the require and recoded the header a bit on that specific site so the judges won't be too happy but hey, it works. Thanks for the help!