# how to set up php sessions for multiple pages based on role

Tags: php, session, mysqli

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (empty(isset($_SESSION['user']))) {
    header('location:index.php');
}
if (isset($_SESSION['role']) == 'admin') {
    header('location:admin.php');
}
if (isset($_SESSION['role']) == 'agent') {
    header('location:user.php');
}
if (isset($_SESSION['role']) == 'supervisor') {
    header('location:supervisor.php');
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP MySQL Role Based Access Control</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h3>PHP MySQL Role Based Access Control</h3>
        <form method="POST" action="includes/login.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>UserName:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>PassWord:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; }?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

// trying to add some sessions for various login users if they accidently closed the browser window before they log out it should redirect them to the reffered pages not to index pages

Comment: You need to change `isset($_SESSION['role']) == 'admin'` to `isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'admin'` (and the same for the other two tests)

Comment: thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope it will help you.

```
session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['user']['user_id'])) {
            if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin') {
                header('location:admin.php');

            } else if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'agent') {
               header('location:user.php');

            } else if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'supervisor') {
               header('location:supervisor.php');
            }
```

Comment: Should probably throw an `exit` in there  after each call to `header`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php

Comment: if this answer is helpful for you then please upvote.